# Windows CE 6.0 | как поставить в VirtualBox ?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-ce

Суть задачи. Есть несколько exe файлов для Windows CE 6.0. Хочу их "поковырять", но для этого надо их запускать. Как сделать виртуалку с WindowsCE на борту?

p.s. Скачал ISO с microsoft.ru, а он не загрузочный. Почитал гугл, как-то все сложно ))

Answer (score 1):

[QEMU](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) Вам поможет

Answer (score -1):

В [первой ссылке](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=49287) в [гугле](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Windows+CE+virtualbox) пишут:

```
The Windows CE emulator is an application which runs inside a Windows OS. The download is a setup.exe file.To run it in a vm, install a Windows OS (such as XP), download the setup.exe and install it in Windows.
```

что означает: Ставь XP и поверх него инсталь CE.

Comment: 1. По первой ссылке пишут про CE 5.0 эмулятор.. под 6.0 нету такого2. я поставил (?) windows CE 6 на windows 7 . Получилось иерархия папок и файлов.. и чо) где система))

Comment: На XP не ставится. Пишет эмулятор не совместим. Ни 5-ый, ни 6-ой CE